# How can I change the Terminal console color in OSX without opening a new console?

Tags: macos

I know how to do this via Terminal > Preferences, but this seems to require opening a new console.  I'd like to change the background color on the current console.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Menu: Shell > Show Inspector  (⌘I)

Double-click on the desired setting. Naturally you'll have to add your desired colour scheme using Preferences first.

Comment: Is possible to do this in the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a command you can enter in Terminal like I suggested in [a similar topic](https://superuser.com/questions/187591/os-x-terminal-command-to-change-color-themes/209920#209920).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the command line too, with a command such as;

```
tput setab 6
clear
```

This changes the background to a teal colour.