# How to set up a context-aware Terminal in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to set the theme of the OS X Terminal depending on what you are doing? I would like to have visual cues to avoid making mistakes.

For example,

- "pro" theme as default
- "blue" if you are connected to another server via SSH
- "red" if you have root rights
- *et cetera*

Answer (score 1):

You can do what I suggest in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/187591/os-x-terminal-command-to-change-color-themes/209920#209920) and programmatically change the themes of Terminal. Combine with shell aliases, scripts or functions that wrap calls to e.g. `ssh` to have automated theme changes.

---

You can also configure themes to execute specific commands when they're launched, so you get an "SSH Theme" executing `ssh`, a "root theme" that automatically runs `sudo bash` or something similar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding lines like these in your .bash_profile should do the trick:

```
alias sudo="osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of front window to settings set \"Red Sands\"' && sudo"
alias su="osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of front window to settings set \"Red Sands\"' && su"
alias ssh="osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of front window to settings set \"Ocean\"' && ssh"
```