# Mac terminal propmt color for specific directories

Tags: macos, unix, colors, terminal.app

I'm looking to setup **visual alerts** when **working within certain directories** within mac osx **terminal**.

Specifically, I have several projects running within the same framework which can easily lead to mistakes. I end up running a `pwd` before other commands if I've been away for the terminal windows for more than a few moments. Seems like a dumb extra step.

All resources I've found are just about setting up color profiles in my bash profile :(

**UPDATED**
*Here is the answer so far (does bark a note, doesn't work for color). Read below for why.*

```
#! /bin/bash -i

# Add this to ~/.bash_profile
# PROMPT_COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/coloraware

PROJECT1='projectfolder/'
PROJECT2='projectfolder2/'
PROJECT3='projectfolder3/'
PWD=`pwd`

case "$PWD/" in
    *$PROJECT1*)
        export PS1='\[\e[1;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\] '
        echo "Project #1"
        ;;
    *$PROJECT2*)
        export PS1='\[\e[1;34m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\] '
        echo "Project #2"
        ;;
    *$PROJECT3*)
        export PS1='\[\e[1;35m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\] '
        echo "Project #3"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OS X Terminal command to change color themes](http://superuser.com/questions/187591/os-x-terminal-command-to-change-color-themes)

Comment: This is what I was referring to above as NOT the issue. All resources out there are just how-to-set-colors-all-the-time guides.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of your terminal session as explained in [@DanielBeck's answer here](https://superuser.com/a/209920/48078).

You could wrap the call to `osascript` in a shell script that pulls your current working directory, then put that shell script somewhere into your `$PATH`, or possibly even into your command prompt `PS1`.

For example, if the basename of the working directory is my home folder, then run the  AppleScript command to change colors (or, in this case, just nag me with a dialog).

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(basename $PWD) = "werner" ]; then
  osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "foo"'
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the color link and getting me on target with comparisons. Don't understand how this gets called automatically while in a folder to do the chirping or coloring. (Tried placing a direct link to the script into my $PATH in .bash_profile)

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585397/bash-run-some-command-before-or-after-every-command-entered-from-console

Comment: @doublejosh Ah, fair enough — maybe just post your answer here and mark it as accepted yourself :)

Comment: Still dealing within settings the PS1 within a script. Added `#! /bin/bash -i` to my header, but can't seem to set the color within the script. Will post the final result for sure!

Comment: These folks seem to be doing so in a script, but I just can't get it to stick. http://serverfault.com/questions/4889/what-are-some-informative-and-useful-shell-prompts-bash-csh-ksh-etc Assume it's because the script swapped the color and parent shell stayed the same. Seems like the answer might be in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905524/ps1-pwd-doesnt-work-from-shell-script or here http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash with `--rcfile`